# Regular expression for preg_replace

Tags: php, regex

Can you help me please what is the regular expression for this string change in preg_replace?

from "On the day, he is playing" to "he is good to play".

Comment: You have to specify some rules, like *remove everything before the first comma*. Something like that. We don't know these rules. Good resource to learn regular expressions: http://www.regular-expressions.info/ . Good luck!

Comment: Another good regex tool: http://refiddle.com/, which lets you build regexes on the fly and test them as you go.

Answer (score 2):

```
preg_replace("/On the day, he is playing/", "he is good to play", $input);
```

Comment: Thank You.Is there any regular expression pattern to find "," and remove the string upto "," and replace remaining part,bcoz I am new to regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replace anything coming after the last comma "," in a string, try this:

```
preg_replace("/[^,]*$/", " he is good to play", $input, 1);
```